# firebase deep query web

Tags: javascript, database, firebase

I need to get a deep query from firebase in a web platform.

I have the following:

- Content

  - User ID 1

    - Time Stamp 1

      - userField 1
      - userField 2
      - userField 3
      - userField 4
    - Time Stamp 2

      - userField 1
      - userField 2
      - userField 3
      - userField 4
  - User ID 2

    - Time Stamp 1

      - userField 1
      - userField 2
      - userField 3
      - userField 4
    - Time Stamp 2

      - userField 1
      - userField 2
      - userField 3
      - userField 4

I can call the following:

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Content").child("User ID 1")
```

Which doesn't help as I need to get all users information into one table.

If I use the following:

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Content")
```

nothing calls?

I understand that firebase uses a shallow call, but how do I get around it?

Comment: It should be no problem to get everything under Content with a single listener.  What exactly is not working the way you expect?

Comment: I would like to call multiple users at the same time, but I can only call one user

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach a listener to the `Content` node and iterate through the received snapshot:

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Content")
rootRef.once('value', function(snap){
    //The function above will execute for each user
    snap.forEach(function(snapshot){
        var user = snapshot.val();
        //Do something 
    });
});
```